# Max and offset in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have some list data and I want to do pagination. But I don't understand how to use 'max'. Here is my simple query code,

```
def users = User.where{
  roles {
     id in roles.id 
  }
}.list(max: 1)
println users
```

- When I set max to 1, it shows 1 data,
- I set max to 2, it shows 2 data,
- I set max to 3, it shows 2 data,
- I set max to 4, it shows 3 data and
- I set max to 5, it shows 4 data

And I didn't understand what is offset. If I want show 5 data per page, What is my offset should be ?

Comment: On the first page, I have to set ' max:6, offset :0 '.
Second page, I have to set ' max:5, offset : 6',
third page, I have to set ' max:5, offset : 11'.

I thought it is stranged.

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/wschat/WsChatContService.groovy#L97 take a look here or the mailinglist plugin on my list.. they all use the offset / max - max is amount of entries per page offset is where to being the record set from

Answer (score 2):

Write like this one, I took it from official docs:

```
def users = User.createCriteria().list (max: 10, offset: 10) {
    roles {
        'in'('id', roles*.id) 
    }
}
```

link to [createCriteria docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)
You can take on controller params.offset and params.max and use it in those criteria.
For example:

```
def users = User.createCriteria().list (max: params.max, offset: param.offset) {...}
```

I think you can add some links under list of elements with offset what you want.
Good luck :)